# $this->Model->id not working before saveAll in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following code in CakePHP 2:

```
$this->Order->id = 5;
$this->Order->saveAll(array(
    'Order' => array(
        'person_id' => $this->Session->read('Person.id'),
        'amount' => $total,
        'currency_id' => $code                   
    ),
    'Lineitem' => $lineitems  /* a correctly-formatted array */
));
```

I would expect this to update the row with the Primary Key of 5 in the `Order` table and then insert the `Lineitem` rows with an order_id of 5.

However, all it does is create a new row in `Order` and then use the new id from the new `Order` record to create the `Listitem` rows.

**Note:** I'm only setting the ID as above for debugging purposes and to easily demonstrate this question. In my final code, I'll be checking to see if there's already a pending order with the current `person_id` and doing `$this->Order->id = $var;` if there is and `$this->Order->create();` if there isn't.

In other words, sometimes I will want it to INSERT (in which case I will issue `$this->Order->create();` )  and sometimes I will want it to UPDATE (in which case I will issue `$this->Order->id = $var;` ). The test case above should produce an UPDATE but it's producing an INSERT instead.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array you pass to `Model->saveAll()` doesnt't contain the order's id, so Cake creates a new one. If you wanto to update an existing record, either you set the order id in the passed array, or you retrieve it with a find. [The documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-save-array-data-null-boolean-validate-true-array-fieldlist-array) explicitly remarks

> If you want to update a value, rather than create a new one, make sure
>   your are passing the primary key field into the data array

```
$order = $this->Order->findById(5);
// ... modify $order if needed
$this->Order->saveAll(array('Order' => $order, 'LineItem' => $items));
```

In your case, you may want to use something like the following to be as concise as possible. `Model::saveAssociated()` is smart enough to create or update depending on the `id`, but you must provide suitable input. `Model::read($fields, $id)` initializes the internal `$data`: for an existing record all fields will be read from the database, but for a nonexistent id, you'll need to supply the correct data for it to succeed. Assuming an order `belongsTo` a customer, I supply the customer id if the order doesn't exist

```
// set the internal Model::$data['Order']
$this->Order->read(null, 5);
// You may want to supply needed information to create
// a new order if it doesn't exist, like the customer
if (! $this->Order->exists()) {
    $this->Order->set(array("Customer" => array("id" => $customer_id)));
}
$this->Order->set(array('LineItem' => $items));
$this->Order->saveAssociated();
```

As a final note, it seems you are implementing a shopping cart. If that's the case, maybe it'd be clearer to use  a separate `ShoppingCart` instead of an `Order` with a `finalized` flag.

Comment: But if I did that, it'd break if there was no id unless I created two separate saveAll commands (one with, one without) and put them in a conditional statement which seems like a needless duplication of most of the code. 

According to the manual ( http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-save-array-data-null-boolean-validate-true-array-fieldlist-array ) you can force an update by doing `$this->Model->id = 5` beforehand.

Comment: @Joseph , the very same paragraph you linked states *If you want to update a value, rather than create a new one, make sure your are passing the primary key field into the data array*

Comment: Yes, but it also implies that calling `$this->Model->id = 5` first will do exactly that, pass the primary key field into the data array.

Comment: I can't understand you. You don't have to trust me, but if your code doesn't work... `$this->Model->id` sets the id of the internal `Model::$data`. Unfortunately, this array is not merged with the one passed to `Model::saveAssociated($data)`. [Look at the sources](http://api20.cakephp.org/view_source/model#line-2185) (or use a debugger). Really I can't understand why you don't *like* my solution: it's simple, concise and **works**

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't that I didn't like your answer, it's just that I understood from the docs that `$this->Model->id = 5` should be doing what I wanted when actually it shouldn't. Anyway, I just implemented your solution and it works perfectly so thanks! Thank you also for your other suggestion about making a separate `ShoppingCart` -- can you point me to any examples of how the Models would be related. I can't immediately see why it would be a better way of doing it, but if I saw an example it'd probably become clear. Thanks again!

Comment: @Joseph each `ShoppingCart` belongs to a `User` (both `Customer` and guest users may add items to their shopping carts). The controller will define a `checkout` action, and at the end of the process (typically after accepting a payment) you'll place an `Order` by copying items from the shopping cart.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried following:

```
$this->Order->saveAll(array(
    'Order' => array(
        'id' => 5,
        'person_id' => $this->Session->read('Person.id'),
        'amount' => $total,
        'currency_id' => $code                   
    ),
'Lineitem' => $lineitems  /* a correctly-formatted array */
));
```

Its pretty much the same what you did with :

```
$this->Order->id = 5;
```

Maybe that would fix your problem. 
Cake is checking if you set id field and if its there it updates record, if not found it creates new record instead.

update:
Then maybe check before you saveAll if there is id field, then save result of check to some boolean and create array to save determined by this boolean for example:

```
if($id_exist) $order['Order']['id'] = 5;
$order['Order']['id'] = 5;
$order['Order']['person_id'] = $this->Session->read('Person.id'),
$order['Order']['amount'] = $total;
$order['Order']['currency_id'] = $code;

    $this->Order->saveAll(array(
    'Order' => $order,
'Lineitem' => $lineitems  /* a correctly-formatted array */
));
```

Comment: Yes, that would definitely work. But there won't be an id in every case and I will actually WANT an INSERT. I've updated the question to make this a little clearer.

Comment: I've updated answer so that it covers the case when your id not exist and you want your record inserted.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to update your answer. It works well but I've gone with Raffaele's solution as the code is a little more concise.